# Hack Assembly, How to do an xor function between 2 values and store the result?

Tags: assembly, logic, nand2tetris

Hi I’m doing hack assembly for the first time, I need to store two values and then use a Xor function and store the result. There are barely any resources on hack and I’m new to it so any help would be appreciated

I can store the two initial values but don’t know how to do an XOR function

Comment: What other functions *do* you know how to do?  You might be able to combine them into an XOR.

Comment: If this is the same hack language as [documented here](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/expressions-and-operators/bitwise-operators) or [here](http://www.jk-quantized.com/experiments/HomebrewComputer/Cheatsheets/hackASM.html#sec_Computation), then it has a `^` operator as usual. If you don't have `xor` you can implement it using boolean logic from the other operators.

Comment: [tag:hacklang] isn't an assembly language, so I assume you mean https://www.nand2tetris.org/software .  I edited the tag; edit yourself if you mean something else.

Answer (score 2):

The original Hack from Nand2Tetris has

- addition
- subtraction
- and'ing,
- or'ing
- negation (2's complement)
- not (aka 1's complement)

---

There's two conditions under which A XOR B is true:

- if A is 1 and B is 0
- if B is 1 and A is 0

Thus, we can compose XOR from the above other primitives, by giving formula to those two conditions, and then combining them together, using either logical OR or addition.

- if A is 1 and B is 0 ***OR*** if B is 1 and A is 0

(Addition works as well as logical OR when the two conditions are mutually exclusive, since there can be no carry; some educational machines don't offer logical OR!)

---

Hack does have the OR operation, so we don't need to use addition (as a substitute like we do with LC-3).

---

| A | B | NOT A | NOT B | A AND NOT B first condition | B AND NOT A second condition | (A AND NOT B) + (B AND NOT A) also (A AND NOT B) OR (B AND NOT A) | A XOR B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

So, if you can either logical-OR or Add, and also negate and logical-AND two values you can replicate that kind of code sequence needed to do the unary and binary operators that will yield XOR.